# AJAX Post no longer works when using DataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I know this is some pretty old technology, but this issue with Datatables has been bothering me, and I haven't found a satisfactory answer on SO that deals with this specifically.

In my code, I have the following AJAX call. It serializes my form, posts the data to my .NET MVC controller, and no errors occur.

```
var url = "/Student/SectionSearch/";
var vm = $('#sectionSearchForm').serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: vm,
    success: function (result) {
        return false;
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Failed to load sections. Please try again.');
    }
});
```

Here is the heavily stripped-down form.

```
@model ViewModels.SectionSearchVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("SectionSearch", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "sectionSearchForm" }))
{
    <div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CalendarId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CalendarId, Model.Calendars, "")
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StructureId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StructureId, Model.Structures, "")
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PeriodId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PeriodId, Model.Periods, "")
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TermId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TermId, Model.Terms, "")
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SectionId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SectionId, Model.Sections, "")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input id="submitSectionSearch" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
}
```

In my MVC controller, I can see that the object was populated correctly, and a JSON-encoded list of my objects is returned without issues.

```
public JsonResult SectionSearch(SectionSearchVM vm)
{
    StudentSearchResults results = _userService.GetStudentsBySectionId(vm.SectionId);
    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now I'd like to run the **exact same** AJAX call, but from within the Datatables construct.

```
$('#resultsDataTable').DataTable({
    info: false,
    bFilter: false,
    bLengthChange: false,
    iDisplayLength: 10,
    dom: 'rtp',
    order: [[1, "asc"]],

    language: {
        emptyTable: "There are no students that meet your search criteria."
    },
    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: vm,
        dataSrc: function (result) {
            ... data manipulation ...    
            return result.Results;
        },
    },
    "autoWidth": false,

    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": 0,
            "data": "StudentNumber",
        },
        {
            "targets": 1,
            "data": "FullName",
            "width": "70%"
        }
    ]
});
```

Inexplicably, this fails on the Controller side. The action is called correctly, but when debugging the code, I can see that my VM object is empty (all properties NULL).

I've tried doing some creative things to the datatables data object, including JSON.stringify(), serialize(), data: { "data": vm } but to no avail. I **could** change the endpoint to just accept a long query string of values, but to me, that defeats the purpose of serialization, and still doesn't explain why my AJAX call fails under slightly different circumstances.

Am I missing something fundamentally obvious here?

Update:
It turns out there is a huge difference in the payloads that are passed between the standard AJAX call and the datatables version...

Standard:

> CalendarId=6019&StructureId=10462&PeriodId=50141&TermId=21203&SectionId=3314793

Datatables:

> 0%5Bname%5D=CalendarId&0%5Bvalue%5D=6019&1%5Bname%5D=StructureId&1%5Bvalue%5D=10462&2%5Bname%5D=PeriodId&2%5Bvalue%5D=50141&3%5Bname%5D=TermId&3%5Bvalue%5D=21203&4%5Bname%5D=SectionId&4%5Bvalue%5D=3314793

Clearly that is part of my problem, but I still don't understand the hows or whys of it.

Comment: "_fails on the controller side_" - with what error? Sounds like you are saying there is no error. Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: What does your JSON response look like? What is the JSON's structure? I ask because I am wondering why you need a `dataSrc` function and why you need `... data manipulation ...`. If the response is an array of arrays, or an array of objects, then that is what DataTables expects (the outer array may be named or unnamed - we would need to see that also).

Comment: @andrewJames No error. My object is simply empty in the controller's endpoint. Nothing of relevance is returned because of this. The data manipulation on return is simply to hide/show divs and do other things unrelated to the datatable display.

Comment: Sorry about that - I completely misread the question.

Comment: In your first code block you say that no errors occur, but how can you be certain since you don't do anything with the response? It would be useful to `console.log(result)` instead of returning `false` to see what data you get back from the server.

Comment: @mark_b I set a breakpoint in the controller and debugged through Visual Studio. I can see that the class object is empty when I enter the method.

Comment: After your update, a couple of observations: (1) for `data: vm` - if that `vm` needs to be populated dynamically (different values for different requests), then you have to use the version of the [`data` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) which uses a function: `"data": function ( d ) { ... }`. Otherwise every dataTables ajax call will use the value of `vm` when the DataTable was first initialized - and maybe that is just `null` at that point.

Comment: (2) Are you familiar with [percent encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding), where `%5B` is `[` and so on? It may also help to see what your form looks like, so we can see what the serialized data looks like. What you show in your question is a collection of name/value pairs: `0[name]=CalendarId&0[value]=6019&1[name]=StructureId&1[value]=10462&...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a satisfactory reason for why this occurs with DataTables, so I'm back to using workarounds.

Here is the setup I went with, in the off-chance this might help someone else.

```
var vm = $('#sectionSearchForm').serializeArray();
var url = "/Student/SectionSearch/" + "?" + vm;

$('#resultsDataTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'rtp',
    order: [[1, "asc"]],
    language: {
        emptyTable: "There are no students that meet your search criteria."
    },
    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": 0,
            "data": "StudentNumber",
        },
        {
            "targets": 1,
            "data": "FullName",
            "width": "70%"
        }
    ]
});
```

Essentially, I nulled out the data parameter, and attached the serialized form as a huge query string on my URL. Not ideal, but it satisfied the DataTables construct.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the form selector, where data is not **serialize**

as you using

```
var form = $('#sectionSearchForm');
    var vm = $(form).serializeArray();
```

try these

```
var vm = $("form").serializeArray();
```

and

```
var vm = $("form").serialize();
```

Comment: Good catch, that was an unfortunate parsing error. Didn't solve my issue, but I'll give you a point for noticing a problem there.